# Are there any easter eggs in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was just playing Minecraft the other day and I began to wonder. Are there any easter eggs in Minecraft, and if so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the more notable easter eggs include these:

- Any mob that is renamed "Dinnerbone" will be rendered upside-down.
- Sheep that are renamed "jeb_" will appear to change color continously.
- There is a 1/100 chance that the title screen will display the title as "Minceraft".
- An unused area for the Zombie Pigman skin will contain writing saying "THX XAPHOBIA".
- Whenever Notch (the creator of the game) dies in-game, he will also drop an additional apple. (Although apparently this doesn't happen anymore.)
- The update logs for various update on the launcher will frequently show "Removed Herobrine" as a running gag referencing an urban legend about the game.

A full page showing them all can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Easter_eggs) on the Minecraft Wiki.